# Can XHTML and HTML class attributes value start with a number?

Tags: html, xhtml

Can XHTML and HTML class attributes value start with a number?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-class

Answer (score 14):

**No**. [They have to be SGML names.](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html#type-cdata) They "must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

[However, class names that start with a number are supported by IE.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_class.asp)

**EDIT**: meder pointed out that you can use Unicode characters and they seem to work in all browsers. I don't know if it complies with the specifications, but it does seem to validate.
See http://css-tricks.com/unicode-class-names/ and http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/unicode_for_css_class_names

Comment: Your quote refers to ID and NAME tokens. But the value of the class attribute is CDATA.

Comment: @Šime Vidas - I think class is a CDATA list of NAME tokens

Answer (score 6):

No, they cannot. They must begin with a letter. Some browsers may erroneously support them, though.

EDIT: You can start off with unicode escape points and specify the code for a number.

EDIT #2: Test case http://work.arounds.org/sandbox/66/run

Comment: You can specify numbers using hex code points, `.\34 ` is the UTF-8 code for number 4 per http://www.yoursiteisvalid.com/validnews/css-class-not-working-when-name-begins-with-numbers-1000.html/comment-page-1

Answer (score 2):

From [the CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#characters):

> "In CSS3, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors (see [SELECT] [or is this still true])) can contain only the
>   characters [A-Za-z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters 161 and higher, plus
>   the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); **they cannot start with a
>   digit** or a hyphen followed by a digit. They can also contain escaped
>   characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next
>   item). For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?"
>   or "B\26 W\3F". (See [UNICODE310] and [ISO10646].)"

Comment: 2018: this link is broken / incorrect. Quoted text appears nowhere at the linked page, and the # ref is broken. I suspect the text was taken from a draft that embedded CSS2 and was later updated, so that the correct link today (becaues I needed to verify ths myself in updating an old parser!) is: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters