# showing exception when selecting the cssselection in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

```
<h3 class="menuheader expandable " headerindex="1h"><span class="accordprefix"></span>

<h3 class="menuheader expandable " headerindex="2h"><span class="accordprefix"></span>
<h3 class="menuheader expandable " headerindex="3h"><span class="accordprefix"></span>
```

Our application is having the above headers. Each header is having the `headerindex` as an unique value to identify. I have used the below code:

```
WebElement Tab_selection = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("<h3>[headerindex=2h]"));
Tab_selection.click();
```

But it is showing the exception:

> invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified. Could
>   you please help on that

Comment: also i have tried with below WebElement Tab_selection = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("h3[headerindex = 2h]"));
Tab_selection.click();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose `2h` into quotes ([explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6247238/771848)):

```
h3[headerindex="2h"]
```

---

And, *xpath locator* is always an alternative:

```
By.xpath("//h3[@headerindex='2h']")
```