# Why '.tab-content[data-tab=1]' is not a valid selector in JS but valid in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select a class with a specific attribute in JavaScript, as below:

```
var me = document.querySelector('.tab-content[data-tab=1]');
```

But getting the following error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '.tab-content[data-tab=1]' is not a valid selector.
```

I tried to change it to jQuery:

```
$('.tab-content[data-tab=1]')
```

Then it will work.

I tried to change it by adding double quotes:

```
var me = document.querySelector('.tab-content[data-tab="1"]');
```

Then it will also work.

I checked the attribute selector at [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) and in its samples, there are `[target=_blank]`, which does not require double quotes.

So why does removing double quotes not work for JavaScript?

Comment: does this answer the question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247221/css-selectors-cannot-match-numerical-attribute-values-why

Comment: @ProGu, Yes, it answers half ot eh question. Another half is why jQuery works with the selector?

Comment: amazing it works with jQuery, jQuery [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) *Attribute values in selector expressions **must** follow the rules for W3C CSS selectors; in general, that means anything other than a [valid identifier](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) should be surrounded by quotation marks.*

Comment: @ProGu, Thank you very much for providing the document. I think jQuery is designed to more error torrents.