# :not(:first-child) and Jquery 1.8.0

Tags: php, jquery, css-selectors

Using PHP I am displaying row's of data in a table. Each row is a link. Instead of using an `<a>` tag in each table cell I decided to use Jquery to make each `<tr>` tag clickable, except for the first `<tr>` which is the table header, and the first `<td>` because it contains a checkbox.

Check my Fiddle for an example, and code: http://jsfiddle.net/Draven/eQznR/12/

It worked fine with Jquery 1.7.2, but since they updated to 1.8.0 today it no longer works.

I'd like a solution without having to use Jquery 1.7.2 because obviously it's not the proper way of doing it.

Thank you.

EDIT: Thanks to Šime Vidas it's because I have a number as a class (`class=1`).

Comment: You can use `<thead>` and `<tbody>` to section your table.

Comment: I suppose that'll work to get past the first `<tr>` tag, but not for the first `<td>` tag.

Comment: Is it just an example, or does your production code really have class identifiers like '1'?

Comment: You could replace it with `$("table.list-apps-table tr:not(:first-child).1 td").not(":first-child")` http://jsfiddle.net/eQznR/13/ I don't know why it is failing though. I have seen a few more reports of custom selectors not working properly in 1.8

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#characters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the `"1"` class name that screws it up for version 1.8. If you use class names that start with a letter, it will work in 1.8:

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/eQznR/14/

Comment: Actually starting a class or id with a number is not valid html: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089006/can-xhtml-and-html-class-attributes-value-start-with-a-number jQuery is moving toward using native browser selectors and that may be the issue.

Comment: @Fresheyeball: At least IDs starting with digits are valid in HTML 5.

Comment: @Fresheyeball It would have made more sense if you linked the relevant section in the corresponding specification, instead of another SO thread. `:P` Anyways, the link is http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#characters