# lastChild not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8"/>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = 'div'>
    <div id = "1">

    </div>     
    <div id = "2">

    </div>  
</div>         
</body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var lastcommentq   = document.getElementById('div').lastChild.id;
    alert(lastcommentq);
});
```

It should alert the id of the lastchild of the div with the id 'div' which is '2' but I am getting the alert as "undefined". I don't know what I have done wrong. Please help me.

Comment: You are alerting `lastcommentq`, what's that?  Your variable is called `lastchild`.

Comment: if you are using jquery, why are you using getElementById instead of jQuery's native selectors?

Comment: @RocketHazmat That was a mistake . i corrected it..

Comment: Putting your `<script>` completely outside the `<html>` probably works, but it offends even my anti-formalist sensibilities.

Comment: Thanks to all who have answered and commented..thank you very much..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your elements probably have text nodes around them, so the last child node of the outer `<div>` won't necessarily have an "id" attribute.

I'm not sure if all browsers support it, but there's a "lastElementChild" property that explicitly gets only elements, and not things like comment nodes or text nodes. Failing that, you could just loop through the node list looking for type 1 nodes.

Comment: [`lastElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.lastElementChild) seems to work on most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

is this your wanted behaivour?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var lastchild   = $("div").last().attr("id")
     alert(lastchild);
     });


<div id="div">
    <div id ="1">

    </div>     
    <div id="2">

    </div>  
</div>
```

check out this fiddle for live example

http://jsfiddle.net/sHgbF/

Comment: He seems to be looking for something like `$('#div').children('div').last().attr('id')`.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I would have done, but I'm not clear as to if it's what you want:

```
$(function () {
    var lastchild = $('#div div:last-child').attr('id');
    alert(lastchild);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pFjPS/

also, I don't believe classes or ids can start with numbers, so your markup is probably not valid

edit : 
HTML5 supports it, but is not generally recommended.

Comment: IDs cannot start with numbers in HTML 4.01 and prior. I believe classes can start with numbers.

Comment: it doesn't look like classes can either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089006/can-xhtml-and-html-class-attributes-value-start-with-a-number

Comment: Technically they [can in HTML](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#classes), but [not in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#characters)

Comment: point taken. Although HTML without CSS is somewhat useless nowadays. :)

Answer (score 0):

In jquery:

```
$(function(){
  alert($("#div :last-child").attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this approach, since ID is a property and not an attribute.

```
$(function () {
    var lastchild = $('#div div:last-child').prop('id');
    alert(lastchild);
});
```

Comment: ["To achieve the best performance when using :last to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector"](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/). Since we already have a pure CSS selector, `:last-child`, no need for `:last`.

Comment: Wow @rink.attendant.6 thats for the info, use last-child instead from now on

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery way:

```
// assuming the last child is always a div
var lastcommentq = $('#div > div:last-child').attr('id');

// alternatively
var lastcommentq0 = $('#div').children('div').last().attr('id');
```

The JavaScript way:

```
var lastcommentq = document.getElementById('div').lastElementChild.id;
```

Note that this works in all modern browsers and IE 9+. See [lastElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.lastElementChild) on MDN.