# Second last child without jquery

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to find a way to select `#inner3` …

```
 <div id="outer">
      <div id="inner1"> </div>
      <div id="inner2"> </div>
      <div id="inner3"> of interest </div>
      <div id="inner4"> </div>
 </div>
```

… by counting from last (`#inner4`) because sometimes `#2` isn't present …

```
 <div id="outer">
      <div id="inner1"> </div>
      <div id="inner2"> of interest </div>
      <div id="inner3"> </div>
 </div>
```

and there are only 3 items (and so `#inner3` becomes `#inner2`).

Note, `#id` are for clarity's sake, and not really present in my work.

I'm right now using `body > .. > div:nth-child(3)` but counting from top is a problem for me as explained above.

Any solution to this?

Comment: can't you add a class "of-interest" to the div that you're interested in?

Comment: @KaarelKont-Kontson I can't change DOM, this is strictly client-side javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I undestood you correctly you could count from the end with `:nth-last-child()`:

```
.outer *:nth-last-child(2){
  color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 20):

You should be able to grab your element with

```
 documentObject.lastChild.previousSibling
```

where `documentObject` is your `parent`.

#### Edit

*Thank you to David Thomas*: Even more accurate would be  `previousElementSibling` because it returns an Element and not a text node:

```
documentObject.lastChild.previousElementSibling
```

Sources:
[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_element_previoussibling.asp)
[developers.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Childnode.previousElementSibling)

Comment: Bear in mind that this will, in many cases, return the textNode (the white-space) that exists between the elements. `previousElementSibling` might be more reliable (where it exists).

Comment: Good note. I change my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The text node can be a problem in both lastChild and previousSibling
This worked for me:

```
documentObject.lastElementChild.previousElementSibling
```

Found the other part of the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18341945/8486854