# document.getElementsByClassName is not affecting elements

Tags: javascript, php, pagination

I have the following script:

```
$i=1;
echo '<table>';
while($row=mysql_fetch_array){
  echo '<tr class="'.$i.'">';
  echo '<td>'.$row['value'].'</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
  $i++;
}
echo '</table>';

$i=1;
echo '<table>';
while($row=mysql_fetch_array){
  echo '<tr class="'.$i.'">';
  echo '<td>'.$row['value'].'</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
  $i++;
}
echo '</table>';
echo '<script>nr='.mysql_num_rows(query).'</script>';
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    for(i=26; i<=nr; i++){
        document.getElementsByClassName(i).style.display='none';    
    }
});
```

As you probably figured out,i'm trying to create a pagination script.To start with, no, i don't want an already made js pagination script , i want it to create it alone(well with some help in cases when i am blocked on some issues).The first step is to hide the other's elements starting with the 25 tr.But the problem is that the document.getelementsbyclassname dont affect them...At first i used id for tr,and it worked,but only for the first table(because id must be unique,and in my case the value for the id is the same,so i used class).I can't figure out what is the problem...

Comment: It's `getElementsByClassName` not `getElementByClassName`! missing **s**!

Comment: class name cannot starts with number

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089006/can-xhtml-and-html-class-attributes-value-start-with-a-number

Comment: @DhavalMarthak , sorry i miss spelled it in my question.In my code is as it  should be

Comment: @szapio - yes they can -> http://jsfiddle.net/784Lpk9o/

Comment: Did you even try to search for this? [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByClassName)  can clarify all that you've wrong in your code.

Comment: @Teemu , well yes i 've read something,but still couldn't found the problem

Comment: Umh... `gEBCN()` returns a live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) ...

Comment: @PetruLebada can you provide console.log(nr) before your loop?

Comment: @davidkonrad , maybe for js it works but this is not a proper way, because css won`t work, a good practice is to not use names starting with digits

Comment: @szapio, no (or yes, agree:) - it is not a proper way (against the specs) but either way it works, all browsers support it, so that the classes are numbers / digits is not the problem here.

Comment: @szapio : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined .. but i don't understand...i've initiated it

Comment: @PetruLebada Why wouldn't you take a time, and really read the docs I've linked in my comments above?

Comment: @Teemu , i took a quick look at them,but i don't think i will find the answer there...

Comment: No? Don't take a quick-look, read them carefully.

Comment: @Teemu, what you tried to say is that the document.getelementsbyclassname returns a collection(array) ,so i have storage it in a variable and create a loop so the style will affect each class element?

Comment: Yes, exactly, though it's not an array, it's an array-like object. It has indicies starting from `0` to its length-1. If you're starting the loop at some random value, like `26`, and end the loop to another random value (`nr`), you have to make sure, that the collection really has those indices.

Comment: @Teemu , thank you , atleast i have a starting point

Answer (score 0):

No need for class with `$i`.Try with -

```
echo '<tr class="row-class">';
```

And the jquery -

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.row-class').each(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    })
});
```

Add conditions if you need.

Or No need to add class to rows. If the page contains a single table then -

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('table tr').each(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    })
});
```

Comment: the op said very clear what's his problem and what he try to acomplish.Changing his code like this won't help him.

Comment: "said very clear [..] what he try to acomplish" - yes, `As you probably figured out,i'm trying to create a pagination script` - why should there be no pointer to the conceptually better approach? Having classes on the elements from 0...n, what's the point? Could iterate through the child-elements without any classes. And no-one should mention that? CSS and javascript have better built-in functions  ..._and_ concepts; no-one should mention that? Doesn't make sense to me. see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @VolkerK You are right. This could be done without any class.

Comment: ....but probably shouldn't ;-) I meant my comment as a reply to  Memphistoles' comment and to the downvote.

Answer (score -2):

class name cannot starts with digit

[Can XHTML and HTML class attributes value start with a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089006/can-xhtml-and-html-class-attributes-value-start-with-a-number)

you can try assign class 'row'+$i

```
echo '<tr class="row'.$i.'">';
  echo '<td>'.$row['value'].'</td>';
 echo '</tr>';
```

js:

```
 for(i=26; i<=nr; i++){
        document.getElementsByClassName('row'+i).style.display='none';    
    }
```

Comment: and if i badly need to use digit..is there another way to catch an html element than by class and id ?? so i can use digits?

Comment: @PetruLebada as i posted you can add prefix, and that solves the problem or you can use unicode, read thread that i linked there are answers for your question