# Why this is not a valid CSS selector using querySelectorAll in JS?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to find in my DOM all the `img` elements with `2x` class using Vanilla JS. I'm using the `querySelectorAll` method like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('img.2x');
```

But it throws this error at the console log:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document':
'img.2x' is not a valid selector.
```

Why `img.2x` is not a valid selector? Thanks.

Comment: Class selectors can't start with a number, unless you escape it. `"img.\\2x"`

Comment: Class names cannot begin with a digit. See https://www.w3.org/TR/html/dom.html#classes

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089006/can-xhtml-and-html-class-attributes-value-start-with-a-number#4089056

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While it certainly does *look* valid, you'll need to explicitly escape any digits that begin a CSS class in order to use it within your selector:

```
document.querySelectorAll('img.\\2x');
```

Comment: Ahhh okay! I have used the W3C HTML validator and it doesn't throw any error. This only happens with JS right but it's valid to have a class starting with a number in the HTML right?