# Javascript adding a class to an element using the value from an onClick event

Tags: javascript

I have been trawling around all day trying to fix this issue I am sure it is simple but I will be darned if I can figure it out.

I have tried the archive and cannot seem to find the solution to my particular issue, so any help will be very gratefully received!

I am wanting to add a style to an individual element when a list item is clicked. The list Item Id's and associated div classes are created dynamically in my php code.

With my script I have got as far as getting an alert box appearing as a test to show that the onclick event attached to the list item is returning the correct value. In this case ID and class "1995"

However when I add the correctly returned value into my script using

```
document.getElementsByClassName(supplyClass).style.display = "none";
```

In the console I get

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: reply_click is not defined"

Abridged code is below with the succesful alert line commented out.

```js
function reply_click(supplyClass) {
    //alert(supplyClass);
    document.getElementsByClassName(supplyClass).style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="supply-container">
    <div class="supply-menu">
        <ul>
            <li id="1995" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Desking Systems</li>
        </ul>
    <div>
    <div class="supply-content-container">
        <div class="1995 supply-content" >
                    <p>LorumIpsum</p>
        </div>
    </div>            
</div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName(supplyClass).style.display` cannot work since `getElementsByClassName` returns a **list** of elements. However, the error means that `reply_click` is not defined, which could be the case if you have a syntax error in your function. The line itself us syntactically valid, so it might be somewhere else in the code that you didn't post.

Comment: Also reply_click(this.id) will return 1995 instead of classname

Comment: You should use `document.querySelector('.' + supplyClass).style.display  = 'none';`, but that's unrelated to the error you are getting.

Comment: @FelixKling I think that will throw an error in this case since they are using a class name starting with a number. But that's a different issue too.

Comment: @Mark_M I think you are right: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089006/can-xhtml-and-html-class-attributes-value-start-with-a-number

Comment: Thanks for the answers everyone. I didn't realise you cannot start a class name with an integer have something to work on will hopefully post an answer shortly ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your event handler is passing `id` of clicked element you need to use `document.getElementById` to find the element and make the display to none as below

```js
    function reply_click(supplyClass)
{
    alert(supplyClass);
    //document.getElementsByClassName(supplyClass).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(supplyClass).style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="supply-container">
    <div class="supply-menu">
        <ul>
            <li id="1995" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Desking Systems</li>
        </ul>
    <div>
    <div class="supply-content-container">
        <div class="1995 supply-content" >
                    <p>LorumIpsum</p>
        </div>
    </div>            
</div>
```

Comment: Pretty sure the OP wants to find the element with *class* `1995`.

Comment: @FelixKling i agree but as he has explicit id set for the ul element as well so i wasn't 100% sure

Comment: You are correct Felix and thanks both for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName(supplyClass)` returns list of elements so you can't set its style directly.

If you want to set style for all elements returned this way then you can do it like this.

```
const els = document.getElementsByClassName(someClass);

for (let i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  els[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Felix & Sumeet The line of correct code that worked is as follows.

```
document.querySelector('.supply-' + supplyClass).style.display = 'none';
```

I had not realised you cannot start a class name with an integer so appended the word supply with a hyphen to the supplyClass value and it worked fine.

Thanks again.